# Magento 2 : Cart Total Not Updating

Tags: magento2, product, cart, totals

I added simple product with options programmatically into cart using this code.

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller\Customer;

class Myclass extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $custsession;
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_appRequestInterface;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $custsession,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $appRequestInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager)
    {
        $this->custsession = $custsession;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_appRequestInterface = $appRequestInterface;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if($this->custsession->isLoggedIn())
        {
            try
            {
                $params = [
                          'product' => 12,
                          'selected_configurable_option' => NULL,
                          'related_product' => NULL,        
                          'options' => [
                              3 => 8,
                          ],
                          'qty' => 2
                ];

                $product = $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(12);
                $mycartp = $om->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
                $mycartp->addProduct($product,$params);
                $mycartp->save();

                $quote = $om->get('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
                $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();

                $checkout = $om->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
                $checkout->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();

                $message = "Your quote has been successfully added to cart";
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess($message);

                $accUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/');
                $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($accUrl)->sendResponse();   
                exit;

            }
            catch(\Exception $e)
            {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $accUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('extension/controller/mypage');
                $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($accUrl)->sendResponse();   
                exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $accUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/login');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($accUrl)->sendResponse();   
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

The product sucessfully added to cart with options, but it not show correct subtotal in cart page and mini-cart. See below screen-sort.

[image]

One's I click on "Update Shopping Cart" it show correct total. See below screen-sort.

[image]

Any one know about this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

Please replace below code with my code :

Replace This :

```
 $quote = $om->get('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
 $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();

 $checkout = $om->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
 $checkout->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
```

Replace With :

```
$quoteRepository = $om->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface');
$quoteObject = $quoteRepository->get($mycartp->getQuote()->getId());
$quoteObject->setTriggerRecollect(1);
$quoteObject->setIsActive(true);
$quoteObject->collectTotals()->save();
```

Above code works for me. So please try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can recalculate the cart total using the below code

```
$quote->setTriggerRecollect(1);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```